# Select second tab in JQuery mobile tab view

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using JQuery mobile tab. Based on some condition, I want the second tab to be selected showing the corresponding tab view. Appreciate the help :)

```
<!-----HTML------->
<div class="custom-tabs" id="tabDiv">
    <div data-role="navbar" class="">
        <ul>
            <li name=""><a href="#one" id="firstTab" data-ajax="false" data-theme="c">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li name=""><a href="#two" id="secondTab" data-ajax="false" data-theme="c">Tab 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
     <!--- First Tab --->
    <div id="one" class="tab-content-wrap" name="tabOneContentId"></div>

    <!--- Second Tab --->
    <div id="two" class="tab-content-wrap" name="tabTwoContentId"></div>            
</div>


<!------JS------>
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#requestServiceHome", function() {
    $("#tabDiv").tabs();
    if(flag == true){
        $('#tabDiv').tabs("option", "select", 1 );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `data-role="tabs"` on the container DIV:

```
<div class="custom-tabs" id="tabDiv" data-role="tabs">
```

Then to set active tab:

```
$('#tabDiv').tabs("option", "active", 1 );
```

When you do this, the corresponding tab button does not change color. So you either need to add the ui-btn-active class to the button, or trigger the button click instead of setting the active tab, e.g:

```
$("#secondTab").click();
```

Comment: ezanker: I am using `$(secondTab).trigger("click");` which seems to work, But we can clearly see a transition from first tab to the second. I was wondering, if there is a way to hide the transition. Anyways thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Sumanth, you can use the first option and set the ui-btn-active class on the tab button: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/a84dajrv/